# Sequence of functions - showing the series converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider the sequence of functions 
$$f_n:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\qquad f_n:=(-1)^n(1-x)x^n,\qquad n\geq 0.$$

Show that the series  $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

I'm having trouble with the proof and looking for help, thanks :)

Comment: The series doesn't have to be absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the summation formula of geometric sums, the partial sums are
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}(1-(-x)^{n+1}).
$$
Considering the cases $0\leq x<1$ and $x=1$ separately, we see that this converges pointwise to

> $$
> f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}f_k(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}\qquad\forall x\in[0,1].
> $$

So the remainder is
$$
R_n(x)=f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}\left(1-(1-(-x)^{n+1})\right)=\frac{(1-x)(-x)^{n+1}}{1+x}.
$$
An easy study of the derivative of the nonnegative function $g_n(x):=(1-x)x^{n+1}$ on $[0,1]$ shows that its maximum is attained for $x=\frac{n+1}{n+2}=1-\frac{1}{n+2}$. Hence
$$
\sup_{[0,1]}\;|R_n(x)|\leq g_n\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\frac{1}{n+2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{n+2}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\;\; \sup_{[0,1]}\;|R_n(x)|=0
$$
that is, the series converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

First, since $f_n(x)$ is alternating, and $f_n(x) \to 0$, the series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges, so $f(x)$ is well defined.

If $x \in[0,1)$ we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n  = \frac{1}{1+x}$, and so we have $(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. In particular, $|(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n| \le 1-x $ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Now consider
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n (1-x)x^n| &=& |\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty (-1)^n (1-x)x^n |\\
&=& |\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+N+1} (1-x)x^{n+N+1} | \\
&=& x^{N+1} |\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n} (1-x)x^{n} | \\
&\le& x^{N+1}(1-x) \\
& \le & \frac{1}{N+1}(\frac{N+1}{N+2})^{N+1} \\
& \le & \frac{1}{N}
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize that $x^n\leq 1$ when $|x|\leq 1$...(+1).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\:\:\frac{\text d }{\text dx}\sum_j f_j(x)=\sum_j \frac{\text d }{\text dx} f_j(x)\:$ and try to show that the latter converges uniformly over $\:\bigcup_{\delta>0}[\delta,1-\delta]\:$ for any such *fixed* $\:\delta\:$ and since $\:f_n\:$ converges uniformly trivially at $\:x_n\in\{0,1\}\:$ this will show that the series of functions is continuous over the compact $\:\mathcal K=[0,1],\:$ which is a necessary condition for it to converge uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Put
$$F(x) = \sum f_n(x)\mbox{,}\qquad F_n(x)=\sum^n_{k=0}f_k(x)\mbox{.}$$
By Abel's theorem, since the series converges at $1$, $F$ is continuous at $1$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Fix a positive even integer $n_0$. Observe that for $n\geq n_0$,
$$F_{n_0}(x)\geq F_n(x)\geq0\qquad(0\leq x\leq1)\mbox{.}$$
Choose $1>\delta>0$ so that
$$0\leq F(x)\leq F_{n_0}(x)<\epsilon/2$$
for $x\in[1-\delta,1]$. It follows that for $n\geq n_0$, $x\in[1-\delta,1]$,
$$\begin{aligned}
\lvert F_n(x)-F(x)\rvert&\leq \lvert F_n(x)-F_n(1)\rvert+\lvert F_n(1)-F(1)\rvert+\lvert F(1)-F(x)\rvert\\
&\leq F_{n_0}(x)+F(x)<\epsilon\mbox{,}
\end{aligned}$$

By the Weierstrass M-test, $F_n\rightarrow F$ uniformly on $[0,1-\delta]$. Hence there exists an integer $N>n_0$ such that $n\geq N$ implies
$$F_n(x)-F(x)\leq\epsilon$$
whenever $x\in[0,1-\delta]$. Consequently, $F_n\rightarrow F$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.